# Is there a continuous bijection from a segment of $\mathbb{R}$ to the following subset of $\mathbb{Q}_2$?

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, continuity, p-adic-number-theory

> Is there a continuous bijection from a segment of $\mathbb{R}$ to the following subset of $\mathbb{Q}_2$?

For any element $x$ of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ let $\displaystyle x=2^z\frac{p}{q}r$ where $z\in\mathbb{Z}, p, q$ coprime odd, and $r$ contains the residual factors.

If I define a subset of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ as follows:

$X=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}_2:q=1\}$

Does there exist a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ or from a segment of $\mathbb{R}$ to $X$?

I may need to define "continuous". If so, I need a bijection such that it maps a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}$ to a continuous function in $(X,\lvert\cdot\rvert_2)$.  Hopefully this does that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}_2$ is totally disconnected, so there is no nonconstant continuous map from any interval in $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}_2$.

(Incidentally, your belief is not correct, and the set $X$ you refer to cannot be defined in any natural way unless you mean for it to be all of $\mathbb{Q}_2$. Any element of $\mathbb{Q}_2\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ can be written in that form in more than one way: if one value of $r$ works, so does $sr$ for any nonzero rational $s$ by modifying $z$, $p$, and $q$ to compensate.)

Comment: Yes, I realised the 2nd error moments before your answer! I have attempted to correct.

Comment: Is the 2nd error fixed now?

Comment: What does it mean for $r\in\mathbb{Q}_2$ to have "prime factors"?

Comment: $2\sqrt{2}$ would not be allowed but $\sqrt{2}$ would. Anyhow what I'm trying to say is that $r$ is the residual after the primes are all factored out.

Comment: OK, but what about $\sum a_n 2^n$ where $a_n=1$ if $n$ is prime and $a_n=0$ otherwise?

Comment: Frankly you don't seem to have any understanding of what $\mathbb{Q}_2$ actually is.  I would suggest reading about it in a textbook before trying to discuss things like this.

Comment: Well, every $x$ _can_ be written in that form: just let $r=x$, $z=0$, and $p=q=1$.  But such a representation is never unique, and in most cases there is not even any canonical choice, so it's not meaningful to talk about $q$ as being determined by $x$ as you do in defining $X$.

Comment: It would seem in $\mathbb{R}$ there is a natural way to choose $p,q$ such that the whole powers of any prime are in them and the remainder is in $r$. I assumed this could be replicated in $\mathbb{Q}_2$, perhaps incorrectly.

Comment: No, this is true neither in $\mathbb{R}$ nor in $\mathbb{Q}_2$.

Comment: I see quite clearly that this assumption of mine breaks down, at the very least least for transcendental numbers.

Comment: Am I right in thinking the powers of $2$ are well-defined for any number in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ but the others aren't necessarily? I think this is the mistake I made.

Comment: Yes, you can meaningfully talk about how many times an element of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ is divisible by $2$ (though you need to define divisibility in terms of $\mathbb{Z}_2$), but not any other prime.

Comment: All I wanted to do is define numbers which aren't fractions, i.e. the denominator is $1$.  Is there a natural way to do that in $\mathbb{Q}_2$?  But I mean in the sense $\frac{-1}{3}$ is a fraction so I want to exclude that from $X$.  I appreciate $\sum a_n 2^n=\frac{-1}{3}$ where $a_n=1$ of $n$ is odd and $a_n=0$ otherwise so you might think of it as a whole number in $\mathbb{Q}_2$ but this is the kind of fraction I want to exclude from $X$.

Comment: No, there is no natural way to do that in $\mathbb{Q}_2$.  If you restrict to just elements of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ which are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, you could talk about elements that are integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, but there is nothing along these lines at all for transcendental elements.  (And doing this is not really _natural_ even for algebraic elements--the entire point of using $\mathbb{Q}_2$ is to ignore all primes other than $2$.)

Comment: Ok thanks. You've been more than generous. I need to show Sharkovski's theorem applies to a function $f$ which is continuous on the rationals $X$ as defined above, under the 2-adic metric. The theorem is only proven for segments of $\mathbb{R}$.  So the easiest possibility to translate $f$ into a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ was a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}_2$. Do you have any other suggestions? I knew $\mathbb{Q}_2$ was totally disconnected but not that this ruled out a continuous bijection to $\mathbb{R}$. I don't need transcdtl, or even irrational elements.

Comment: It says here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space that continuous images of totally disconnected spaces are not necessarily totally disconnected. In my limited understanding this contradicts your answer. Why does it not?

Comment: Your question asked about a continuous bijection _from_ $\mathbb{R}$, not a continuous bijection _to_ $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: My lack of skill again... I assumed, incorrectly it would seem, that being a bijection would mean it could not be continuous in one direction and not in the other. I simply need a map that translates a function I have which is continuous in the elements of $X$ which are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}_2$ into one which will also be continuous in $\mathbb{R}$. But even given that, I think I still have the problem of defining some uncountably large extension of the dyadic fractions.

Comment: Just to be clear; you're implying there's a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{Q}_2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, despite it being totally disconnected but not the other way around.  Is that correct?

Comment: No, there does not exist any such continuous bijection.  But I believe there does exist a continuous bijection from a subset of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks. Then it is almost certainly that which I need. What about from $\mathbb{Z}_2$?  Which may also be sufficient for my purposes and may be simpler.